# What is the monotone hazard rate assumption used for?

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, pricing, price-discrimination

I was reading this article on advance purchase discounts and pricing in which the author uses the monotone hazard rate assumption. Why does the author use it?

The article is *Advance-purchase discounts as a price discrimination device* ([PDF](http://www.frankrosar.de/mediapool/135/1350549/data/nockepeitzrosar_apd_2011.pdf)) by Nocke Peitz and Rosar

Below you can find a screenshot of the part in question.

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The motivation for this assumption is to have a unique solution. In this article, it is necessary to prove the 1st lemma, i.e. the quasi-concavity of the profit function.  You find a similar motivation in Tirole’s book (Industrial Organization, p. 156).